# Identify feature issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, identify

When I click to identify a feature it comes up with 'no features found at this position'. It was working fine before so I think it's something to do with the settings. I installed the latest version of QGIS, set the CRS and restarted my Mac. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Make sure you have the layer selected in the layers panel.  Make sure there is a feature from that layer where you are clicking.Try again.

Comment: Make sure you have selected the right layer first.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, yes it does come up now - but not in the same way. I used to be able to select any feature without selecting the layer first. Is there anything in the settings that could change it?

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS, one of the layers is always the active layer even if you do not select it and the selection is performed in the active layer. When you select any layer, you make it the active layer.

*I used to be able to select any feature without selecting the layer first*: You can select items because it is the current active layer even though you are not aware that it is the active layer.

When you select multiple layers, the last layer you selected is the active layer.